# Animating/photoshp a 3d model?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, photo-editing

After finish designing a product and having some `STL` file( the file for 3d printing you get from softwares such as solidWorks), you would like to make some movie of it, and animate it .

For example same as Apple do in its marketing videos, where you see the product zoomed in and camera covering it from many directions.

So,

1. is there software that can do that with stl file ?
2. is there a software except from `Photoshop`(i guess it cant get an STL file) , that you can take a 3d model and put some logos on it and play with lights etc ?

thanks .

Comment: Why didnt you do this in solidworks? Anyway yes there are software for this i can name 30 offhand. What is your budget

Comment: @joojaa So please give me some names :) i need something that lets you do many things such as: change colour, add a fabric to it, add logos, change lights,and also animate and move it. So i need photo editing, and video capabilities.

Comment: Thats not exactly many things its like the bare bone basics of any dcc app.

Comment: its not my area...for me its a lot. in other words, you need to take a 3d model and make it ready for marketing.

Comment: by the way google just won't give anything for this search.

Comment: weird google seems to give me a pretty comrehensive list with about half of everything there is. Anyway Im going to vote this as off topic even if answered you. Your buget really comes into play here.

Comment: @joojaa yea if you search 3d modelling. (or god) . but if you search for something like "movie from stl" or "editing stl" you won't get anything. and that need, i think is very popular this days.

Comment: stl is about the simplest format ever, it wouldn't take more than 20 minutes to implement a stl translator so you can open it in nearly any 3d app.

Answer (score 1):

Sure the big ones:

- 3dS Max
- Blender
- Cinema 4D
- Houdini
- Maya
- Modo
- Lightwave

The Comp software that can do the 3d as side job (sufficient for you)

- After Effects
- Eyeon Fusion
- Nuke

The contenders:

- Creo
- Solidworks
- Catia
- Keyshot

Lots and lots of others.

And the answer google gives:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software

Which is more comprehensive then i have.But still just scratching the surface. Hard to say what is your budget...

PS STL is incredibly simple and can easily be converted to OBJ

Comment: Well if you search 3d modeling obviously you will find many results. That's not what I want. I wanted a simle software that can get an stl and let you apply direct effect to it without hassling,like colors,shades, materials. Everybody knows after effect, i dint need f16 to drive on a highway, it's isn't really what I need. And same as for the camera effects, only moving the camera , not creating complex movies. Sometimes getting a simple answer is harder.